# python programming- average of exams and assignments and print grade

Tags: python

Please im trying to Write a Python program that calculates a student Final grade for a class that has two assignments and two exams. Assignments worth 40% of the class grade and exams worth 60% of the class grade. The program should perform the following steps:

1. Ask the user for assignment1, assignment2, exam1, and exam2 grades. all grades are out of 100 .
2. Calculate the average of the assignments.
3. Calculate the average of the exams.
4. Calculate the final grade using the following formula:
   final grade=.4*average of the assignments+.6*average of the exams.
5. Format the final grade to have 2 decimal places.
6. Display a message telling the student what the final grade is.

here is my program:

```
from math import *

def main():


    Assignment1 = eval(input("Please enter the score for Assignment 1: "))
    Assignment2 = eval(input("Please enter the score for Assignment 2: "))
    Assignment_total = Assignment1 + Assignment2
    Assignment_average = Assignment_total/2
    print("The average of the assignment is", round(Assignment_average, 2))

    Exam1 = eval(input("Please enter the score for Exam 1: "))
    Exam2 = eval(input("Please enter the score for Exam 2: "))
    Exam_total = Exam1 + Exam2
    Exam_average = Exam_total/2
    print("The average of the Exam is", round(Exam_average, 2))


    Final_grade = 0.4 * Assignment_average + 0.6 * Exam_average

    if 90 <= Final_grade <= 100:
        return 'A'
    elif 80 <= Final_grade <= 89:
        return 'B'
    elif 70 <= Final_grade <= 79:
        return 'C'
    elif 60 <= Final_grade <= 69:
        return 'D'
    else:
        return 'F'

main()
```

i cannot get it to print The grades. please help me

Comment: You have to add a print statement, i.e., print("The Final grade is", round(Final_grade, 2)), somewhere in the code., after you calculate Final_grade.

Comment: Are you just looking for `print` instead of `return`? (Your code would then print letter grades, but not the percentages. I'm not sure if you need help with that too?)

Comment: yes i am trying to print the final grade in number and also in letter like  90 : A

Comment: @donzion in my answer I address your problems as well as change the printing format you commented on (i.e. 90 : A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are all over the page here. You have `return` but you are not returning anything (i.e. you would have to call `grade = main()` and then `print(grade)`.

Take a look at my comments below:

```
# nothing you are doing requires the math module
# eval() and round() are built-ins; we dont even need eval()
## from math import *

def main():
    # variable names = short & sweet + meaningful
    a1 = int(input("Please enter the score for Assignment 1: "))
    a2 = int(input("Please enter the score for Assignment 2: "))
    atot = a1 + a2
    aavg = atot / 2
    print ("The average of the assignment is", round(aavg, 2))

    e1 = int(input("Please enter the score for Exam 1: "))
    e2 = int(input("Please enter the score for Exam 2: "))
    etot = e1 + e2
    eavg = etot / 2
    print ("The average of the Exam is", round(eavg, 2))

    fingrd = ((0.4 * aavg) + (0.6 * eavg))

    if (90 <= fingrd <= 100):
        print (fingrd, ': A') # edit: included print format you commented
    # no need to do <= on the upper bounds
    # < upper_bound includes <= your previous lower_bound - 1
    # i.e. 80 <= fingrd < 90 equates to 80 <= fingrd < 90
    elif (80 <= fingrd < 90): 
        print (fingrd, ': B')
    elif (70 <= fingrd < 80):
        print (fingrd, ': C')
    elif (60 <= fingrd < 70):
        print (fingrd, ': D')
    else:
        print (fingrd, ': F')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
Please enter the score for Assignment 1: 70
Please enter the score for Assignment 2: 100
The average of the assignment is 85.0
Please enter the score for Exam 1: 45
Please enter the score for Exam 2: 87
The average of the Exam is 66.0
73.6 : C
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking my suggestion and @Toad22222's and also getting rid of that scary `eval`:

```
from math import *

def main():
    Assignment1 = int(input("Please enter the score for Assignment 1: "))
    Assignment2 = int(input("Please enter the score for Assignment 2: "))
    Assignment_total = Assignment1 + Assignment2
    Assignment_average = Assignment_total/2
    print("The average of the assignment is", round(Assignment_average, 2))

    Exam1 = int(input("Please enter the score for Exam 1: "))
    Exam2 = int(input("Please enter the score for Exam 2: "))
    Exam_total = Exam1 + Exam2
    Exam_average = Exam_total/2
    print("The average of the Exam is", round(Exam_average, 2))


    Final_grade = 0.4 * Assignment_average + 0.6 * Exam_average
    print("The final grade is", round(Final_grade, 2))

    if 90 <= Final_grade <= 100:
        print('A')
    elif 80 <= Final_grade <= 89:
        print('B')
    elif 70 <= Final_grade <= 79:
        print('C')
    elif 60 <= Final_grade <= 69:
        print('D')
    else:
        print('F')

main()
```

**UPDATE**

Kind of a rewrite just for fun. Feel free to ignore or take inspiration or ask questions.

```
import collections

Component = collections.namedtuple("Component", ["name", "count", "weight"])

def get_average(name, how_many):
    return sum(
        int(input("Please enter the score for {} {}: ".format(name, i+1)))
        for i in range(how_many)
    ) / how_many

def main():
    components = [
        Component(name="assignment", count=2, weight=0.4),
        Component(name="exam", count=2, weight=0.6),
    ]

    total = 0
    for component in components:
        average = get_average(component.name, component.count)
        print("The average of the {}s is: {:.2f}".format(component.name, average))
        print()
        total += average * component.weight

    letters = [(90, "A"), (80, "B"), (70, "C"), (60, "D")]
    grade = next((letter for score, letter in letters if total >= score), "F")

    print("The final grade is: {:.2f} ({})".format(total, grade))

main()
```

Comment: I think list comprehension & string formatting may be a bit advanced for the OP at this time! But kudos for the effort!

Comment: Agreed, just figured I'd share. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function by assigning it to a variable to then print. See below:

```
from math import *

def main():
    Assignment1 = eval(input("Please enter the score for Assignment 1: "))
    Assignment2 = eval(input("Please enter the score for Assignment 2: "))
    Assignment_total = Assignment1 + Assignment2
    Assignment_average = Assignment_total/2
    print("The average of the assignment is", round(Assignment_average, 2))

    Exam1 = eval(input("Please enter the score for Exam 1: "))
    Exam2 = eval(input("Please enter the score for Exam 2: "))
    Exam_total = Exam1 + Exam2
    Exam_average = Exam_total/2
    print("The average of the Exam is", round(Exam_average, 2))


    Final_grade = round(0.4 * Assignment_average + 0.6 * Exam_average)

    if 90 <= Final_grade <= 100:
        return "Your final grade is %s: A" %(Final_grade)
    elif 80 <= Final_grade <= 89:
        return "Your final grade is %s: B" %(Final_grade)
    elif 70 <= Final_grade <= 79:
        return "Your final grade is %s: C" %(Final_grade)
    elif 60 <= Final_grade <= 69:
        return "Your final grade is %s: D" %(Final_grade)
    else:
        return "Your final grade is %s: F" %(Final_grade)

mygrades = main()
print (mygrades)
```

Output

```
Please enter the score for Assignment 1: 43
Please enter the score for Assignment 2: 88
The average of the assignment is 65.5
Please enter the score for Exam 1: 90
Please enter the score for Exam 2: 89
The average of the Exam is 89.5
Your final grade is 80: B
```

Comment: You are welcome @donzion, please see the most current update above. Please mark my answer as accepted if it is was the help you needed.